# Change starting values of an iteration in a sequence Python

Tags: python, function, recursion, iteration, return-value

```
fibs = {0: 0, 1: 1}
def fib(n):
    if n in fibs: return fibs[n]
    if n % 2 == 0:
        fibs[n] = ((2 * fib((n / 2) - 1)) + fib(n / 2)) * fib(n / 2)
        return fibs[n]
    else:
        fibs[n] = (fib((n - 1) / 2) ** 2) + (fib((n+1) / 2) ** 2)
        return fibs[n]


def test(n):
    count = range(0,n)
    seq = []
    for i in count:
        seq.append(fib(i))
    return seq

print test(10)

[0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34]
```

how to make it start at 1 and not 0 so the result is

```
[1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
```

I tried changing fibs to {1:1,2:2} but it didn't work

Comment: You can replace `count = range(0, n)` with `count = range(2, n+2)` to get the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

You can replace count = range(0, n) with count = range(2, n+2) to get the expected output. –

via

Nicolas

```
def test(n):
    count = range(2,n+2)
    seq = []
    for i in count:
        seq.append(fib(i))
    return seq
```

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can do two of these things. Suppose your result is stored in fibonacciNumbers.
One option is Slice the list:

```
fibonacciNumbers[2:]
```

Second option is simply pop the first element from fibonacciNumbers.

```
for i in range(2):
    fibonacciNumbers.pop(0)
```

Comment: Only marginally more efficient; popping the first item of a list requires shifting all the other items downward in memory, essentially copying all of them.

Comment: You are right. Instead a collection.deque would make more sense for add / remove operations at the ends. I mean adding/removing at ends is of O(1) in deque. I had a misconception that python's list was a linked list implementation. Anyways I undated my answer. Thanks for clarification.